# Character set change

Tags: raspbian, python

I was using my raspberry pi for the first time in ages. I decided to try doing come code in Python3. I couldn't remember how to return to the command line, but I knew pico used ctrl+x. So I started spamming buttons.

Eventually my font ended up like thing[image]

Can anyone explain what I've done, or how to undo do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try hitting enter a couple times, carefully (since you won't be able to see it properly) typing `reset`, then hitting enter.

[Here's what that's about](http://linux.die.net/man/1/reset) -- you don't really have to read it, the point is it's with regard to the terminal settings, not the system in some more serious sense, so it is harmless even if it doesn't work and won't have any weird side effects.

If that fails, try `reboot`.

For future reference: http://www.python-course.eu/python3_interactive.php Looks like the python shell has a "help" feature and you can exit it via `exit()` or ctrl-d.

Comment: Reboot didn't work and nor did sudo shutdown. I pulled the plug on the pi, and powered it back up. When I then tried to turn it off it wouldn't let me. But the weird character set was reverted. I'm just going to re-image the SD card

Comment: If by "reverted" you mean everything is okay again you shouldn't have to re-image the card.  If it's still screwed up then it is hard to say what's wrong -- it could be simple or it could be "might as well re-image the card" ;)

Comment: I'm only re-imaging because it wouldn't turn off, instead it just goes to root?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "then" in your third sentence.  Sounds like it is probably in, or dropping to, single root user emergency mode.  Not something I've ever been confronted with much, although I think it should still let you shutdown.  I guess it depends how big a deal this is to you and how much digging into it you want to do.